# LINQ query for binding to specific values in a collection of ints

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, blazor

I'm trying to dynamically build dropdown lists within my Blazor form component by using a foreach statement. The form is for a product and a product can be linked to tags. Tags themselves have a tag type and I want to dynamically generate a separate dropdown for each tag type which pulls through all the tags linked to that type and only binds to tags of that tag type.

```
@foreach (var type in tagTypesDto)
{
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <RadzenSelect AllowClear="true" AllowFiltering="true" @bind-Value=@productDto.SelectedProductTags.Where(x => x == type.Tags.Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault()) Multiple="true" Placeholder="@_localizer["PleaseSelect"]" Data=@tagsDto.Where(x => x.TagTypeId == type.Id)
            TextProperty="Name" ValueProperty="Id" Label="@_localizer["ProductAttributes"]" />
    </div>
}
```

I'm unable to get this to build because I'm getting the following error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

I think the issue is the LINQ query I'm trying to pass it for `@bind-Value` - if I replace this with just `@productDto.SelectedProductTags` then it builds and generates a separate dropdown for each tag type, but if I try and select any tags it fails, presumably because it doesn't know which dropdown to assign the tag to.

`SelectedProductTags` looks like this in my product model:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<int>? SelectedProductTags { get; set; } = new int[] { };
```

I'm using .NET 6 and Blazor Webassembly.

Comment: "but if I try and select any tags it fails" what exactly fails when you bind with `productDto.SelectedProductTags`?

Comment: It's really hard to say because it doesn't throw any errors - in VS or in the console. It just whirs for a moment as if it's thinking about it and then does nothing - i.e. the tag I selected does not appear in any of the dropdowns as a selected option.

Comment: You are correct about the trying to use Linq in the binding.  It won't work.  Rethink the design.  With little real context it's hard to suggest what might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a demo project on GitHub with a possible solution to your problem: https://github.com/Jimmys20/SO74219635

You have to use manual event binding:

```
@foreach (var type in tagTypesDto)
{
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        var tagTypeId = type.Id;
    
        <RadzenDropDown Data="tagsDto.Where(x => x.TagTypeId == type.Id).ToList()"
                        Value="productDto.SelectedProductTags"
                        ValueChanged="values => OnValueChanged(values, tagTypeId)"
                        TValue="List<int>"
                        Multiple="true"
                        ValueProperty="Id"
                        TextProperty="Name" />
    </div>
}

@code {
    private void OnValueChanged(List<int> values, int tagTypeId)
    {
        var data = tagsDto.Where(t => t.TagTypeId == tagTypeId).Select(t => t.Id);
        
        productDto.SelectedProductTags.RemoveAll(x => data.Contains(x));
        
        productDto.SelectedProductTags = productDto.SelectedProductTags.Concat(values).ToList();
    }
}
```

`SelectedProductTags` needs to be changed to `List<int>`.